# How to use process monitor to view or log a windows login?

Tags: windows-7, roaming-profile, monitoring

We're having some issues with Windows 7 Roaming profiles and I was reading [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/08/10/3272210.aspx) that the login process can be monitored using process monitor.

> "There are a couple of ways to configure Process Monitor to record
>   logon operations: one is to use Sysinternals PsExec to launch it in
>   the session 0 so that it survives the logoff and subsequent logon and
>   another is to use the boot logging feature to capture activity from
>   early in the boot, including the logon."

How does one do either of these options using process monitor to find out what is happening during a user login?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "There are a couple of ways to configure Process Monitor to record logon operations: one is to use Sysinternals PsExec to launch it in the session 0 so that it survives the logoff and subsequent logon and another is to use the boot logging feature to capture activity from early in the boot, including the logon."

I don't believe that either of the above are valid for Windows 7 for the following reasons:

1. There's no session 0 in Windows 7, as far as I know.
2. User environment debug logging (which is what it sounds like they're recommending) has been replaced/supplanted with the Group Policy event log.

So, my suggestion would be to start by looking at the Group Policy event log on one of the problem machines.

Comment: Is that in Event Viewer?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to find it at: Event Viewer>Applications and Services Logs>Microsoft>Windows>GroupPolicy>Operational

Answer (score -1):

procmon - options - enable boot logging
or
login as admin - start procmon - ctrl alt delete - switch user - login as user
switch back to admin and stop tracing

Comment: What does this work ???