# What log messages do I need to look for that indicate the start of a log-off in Windows Event Viewer?

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, eventviewer, logoff

Is there an Info message in Windows Event viewer that indicates the start of a log off?  I'm trying to spot errors and warnings as a user logs off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you need to have "Audit logon events" enabled in order to see account logon/logoff events in the Security event log.

In addition, if this is in relation to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/432973/how-to-use-process-monitor-to-view-or-log-a-windows-login) question then you can simply look for event 5324 in the GroupPolicy Operational event log, without having to enable account logon auditing.

Answer (score 4):

The security log does track login and logoff events, which should give you a timestamp to look for.

- 4624 -- Logon
- 4625 -- Failed logon
- 4634 -- Logoff
- 4740 -- Account Lockout